# What is the correct way to add a default secret-file to knife.rb?

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

What is the correct format for adding a secret file in my knife.rb?  I've [read the docs](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife_optional_settings.html) and can't seem to get the formatting right, or perhaps it is not working.

I have tried adding both:

```
knife[:secret_file] = "/path/to/data_bag_secret"
```

and

```
secret_file "/path/to/data_bag_secret"
```

Neither of these seem to encrypt my secrets when I use `knife data bag create bag key`

If I use `knife data bag create bag key --secret-file /path/to/data_bag_secret` it encrypts correctly however.

It doesn't appear to be encrypted when I go look at the data bags on https://manage.chef.io, which is why I think it's not encrypting.  When I manually pass the switch it does encrypt correctly on https://manage.chef.io.

Comment: I have the answer from this from Chef support, though I haven't verified it yet.  Hoping to do that today or tomorrow, and answer my own question.  Ping me if you're interested in what they said sooner.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: additionally pass in the command line argument `--encrypt` flag if you are using Chef 12+.  e.g. `knife data bag from file foo ./data_bags/foo.json --encrypt`

Since Chef 12 you are required to pass in the `--encrypt` flag while using `knife data bag [create|from file]` commands in order for your `knife[secret]` or `knife[secret_file` configuration options in knife.rb.  The main problem here is that the chef docs have not yet been updated to indicate as such.  If you call `knife data bag [create|from file] --help` you will see the explanation of the --encrypt flag option there.

Answer sourced here: https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3223#issuecomment-93338211.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: thanks @pableiros, i've updated the original answer and hopefully that is better

Answer (score 0):

So it's a bit odd but the `--secret-file` doesn't populate its own config value. If you look in https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/data_bag_secret_options.rb#L48 you see it runs a custom proc instead, which is defined below that. Setting `knife[:secret_file]` should still work though, all the code related to bag encryption uses both. In general you wouldn't be using `data bag create` for this though, that is for the initial bag/item creation. For general update use `data bag from file`. Also remember that you need to remove that value from your config file to actually see the encrypted data, otherwise `knife data bag show` will decrypt it for you automatically.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be encrypted when I go look at the data bags on manage.chef.io, which is why I think it's not encrypting.  When I manually pass the switch it does encrypt correctly on manage.chef.io.

Comment: Wait I think I misunderstood you.  Are you saying I should try setting that config directly?

Comment: Yes, if you set `knife[:secret_file]` and run a `knife data bag from file` it should encrypt it on upload.